# Within NodeNS, how do you redirect to a specific page inside a Single Page Application?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, angular2-routing

I am serving a single page application (written with Angular5) from a NodeJS server.

On certain conditions I want to serve the application at a specific page. For example if it's a certain time of day I want users to end up at `https://superapp.com/#/happy-hour`

Currently in my server I only know how to serve the whole all as one static unit. 
How do I serve the single application page such that it opens at a specific route?

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect to the route you need on server then parse the route in SPA and render the required content.
Probably smth like that:

```
var cond = true
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    if (cond) {
        response.redirect("/#/test")
        cond = false
        return
    }
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: But how does the server send the route with the SPA?